# Using a count(*) query in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, count

I want to use a query in SSRS report dataset as

```
Select count(*) from tablename where datefieldname<=ParameterDate
```

However, SSRS allows filters only on the fields that are retrieved by the query.

**Can anyone tell me how to apply the parameter filter to the above query and use in SSRS ?**

Thanks

Comment: A COUNT() of the primary key field?

Comment: Can you give a little more information on to what you need? What data is being displayed on the report? Is the data being showed dependent on the Parameter date? If you, you can use `=CountRows("DataSet")` without needing a separate query. If it isn't dependent you should be fine just making a separate dataset for the count.

Comment: Ok

I have a report that needs to just display counts and not the details.

I can use the following query also

"Select JoiningDate from Employees where JoiningDate<=[@DateParameter]" and then use the CountRows to display the data.

But this would be highly inefficient as it would fetch thousands of records and then count at the report level.

I want the count from the database and display it straight on the report.

I know i can use "Select count(JoiningDate)" as well, but what if the where condition contains multiple fields?

Comment: @Nilesh What other fields would be in the `where` condition?

Comment: department='Some department'
city like '%Some city%'

Comment: @Nilesh I think I understand what you are saying, I provided an answer, take a look and we can further the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!SOME_DATE.Value <= Paramaters.ParameterDate.Value, 1, 0))
```

You can add other logic in the IIF with AND and OR.

The IIF will do your logic check. If your criteria is met, a 1 is returned else a 0.

The SUM then sums up all the values from the IIF for all the records.

Comment: There u are.

There is no Fields!SOME_DATE.Value

The retrieved fields list is only the count.

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset query use the following.

```
select count(JoiningDate) 
from tableName
where JoiningDate <= @parameterDate 
and department = @someDepartment 
and city like ('%' + @someCity + '%')
```

and whatever other conditions you need. You will need to have other parameters unless you will always want the same department and city. These parameters can be changed on runtime to get different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can count whatever you like as long as the count is done in the dataset query, SSRS does not care what your query is as long as it works, all it cares about is what is returned.

So let's say you have 2 parameters `@Date` and `@Category` then your dataset query could simply be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCount FROM myTable WHERE myDateColumn <= @Date AND myCategoryColumn = @Category
```

SSRS will just see the `myCount` field in the dataset with your required number in.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would select the your date field in the original query so it can be used against the parameter, then sum the count column in your dataset without grouping on datefieldname to aggregate your filtered results.

```
select datefieldname, count(*) as date_total
from tablename 
where datefieldname<=ParameterDate
group by datefieldname
```